# Is the closure of the direct sum of eigenspaces of an operator $T$ an invariant subspace of $T$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, banach-spaces, invariant-subspace

Let's denote by $T: X \to X$ a closed linear operator on an infinite dimensional Banach space. If needed, we can assume $X = L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for some $p \neq 2, p > 1$.
Furthermore $U_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$, are eigenspaces of $T$ for the eigenvalues $\lambda_i, i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Here comes my question:
If $U$ denotes the closure of the direct sum $\oplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}} U_i$, is then $U$ invariant under $T$?

Of course, the first question already is, if $U$ is contained in the domain of $T$.

Comment: There's no reason why $U$ should be contained in the domain. Consider $X = \ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ and $T(e_n) = 2^n e_n$.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer. Now it's clear that this cannot hold true in such generality.
Anybody an idea, if there are reasonable conditions ensuring invariance if the eigenspaces $U_i$ are finite dimensional but the eigenvectors do not build a Schauder basis as in Daniel's example?

Comment: What exactly is the "direct sum," here?  Do you just mean the closed linear span?  That is, do you mean $U=\overline{\text{span}}(\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}U_i)$ ?

Comment: It is obvious that if $\mathcal{V}$ is a family of $T$-invariant subspaces then $\text{span}\bigcup\mathcal{V}$ is also $T$-invariant. And if $T$ is continuous then so is $\overline{\text{span}}\bigcup\mathcal{V}$.  But I do not think this last fact is true for discontinuous operators, even if $T$ is closed and $\overline{\text{span}}\bigcup\mathcal{V}\subseteq\text{dom}(T)$.

Comment: @BenWallis thanks. That's what I ment with direct sum. And I think so too now, that U usually won't be contained in the domain if T is closed and unbounded.

Comment: Well, it is still an interesting question under what conditions $\textbf{dom}(T)\cap\overline{\text{span}}\bigcup\mathcal{V}$ is $T$-invariant.